# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I am using php and IIS 7.5. Other details of the error:

```
Module  FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/example.php
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

example.php has the following code :

```
<?php
class Persons {
    function say_hello() {
    echo "Hello my name is Sithelo Ngwenya. <br/>"
    }
}
$person = new Persons();
echo get_class($person) . "<br/>";

?>
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Is this the 1st php page you ever tried to run in this server? If not what is example.php doing?

Comment: @killerx No its not the firts page to run. I ran a page that shows my configuration i.e phpinfo.php page. The example.php is my test page and thats the error I got above.

Comment: Then it is most likely a syntax (or similarly fatal) error. It would help if you could post the code you are trying to run. Also do you have any php logging enabled? that might give you a clue as well.

Comment: @KillerX <?php
class Persons {
 function say_hello() {
 echo "Hello my name is Sithelo. <br/>"
 }
}
$person = new Persons();
echo get_class($person) . "<br/>";

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "Hello my name is Sithelo. <br/>"` in you function is missing a `;`.

Comment: Im not working with windows but you might want to look into how to display the PHP error messages in browser in IIS. This will save you days when debugging! :)